# Stripe webhook not firing when charge() method is called

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using the charge() method of the Stripe API to create a payment. In the Stripe dashboard, the payment_intent.created event is being triggered, but my webhook is not firing. When I try to debug my webhook, I get the following error:

```
Error: Call to undefined method Spatie\StripeWebhooks\ProcessStripeWebhookJob::storeWebhook() in file /vendor/spatie/laravel-webhook-client/src/WebhookProcessor.php on line 48.
```

In my debug i also notice that storeWebhook() is a method thatis present in the spatie library that i use.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Additional information:

1. I am using the spatie/laravel-webhook-client package to manage Stripe webhooks.
2. I have verified that my webhook is properly configured.
   Thanks for your help